# Two's complement using logic gates

Tags: boolean-algebra

How can a 4-bit two's complement operation be implemented using boolean NOR gate?
I search lots of 4-bit two's complement videos and articals, but most of them are using XOR gate.

Comment: Two's complement is just a standard how to interpret a number of bits as a number. There is no two's complement operation. 1111 is -1 because I look at it and that's what the label "two's complement" tells me what it is. So what operation are you trying to perform?

Comment: NOR is an universal gate, so it can implement any boolean operation.

Answer (score 1):

A NOR can serve as an inverter, so 1's complement is easy. Now you need to implement two-bit adders to increment the result. A sum is a XOR ($a\oplus b=\overline{\overline{(\overline{(a+b)}+\overline{(\overline a+\overline b)})}}$, and the carry out an AND ($a\cdot b=\overline{\overline a+\overline b}$).

Answer (score 0):

Boolean NOR is universal, so you can [construct an XOR gate or any other gate from NOR gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic), and then use the methods you've read about.