# 7 segment decoder Combinational Logic Circuits using Logic Gates

Tags: boolean-algebra

How can a 7 segment decoder operation be implemented using boolean NOR gate ONLY?

Question:[image]

Here's my truth table and k-map:
[image]

Normal circuit diagram:
[image]

Comment: With the same strategy as for your prior question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156146/755

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following systematic transformation

$$\bigvee_{i=1}^{m}\left(\bigwedge_{j=1}^{n_i} v_{i,j}\right)
=\overline{\left(\overline{\bigvee_{i=1}^{m}\left(\bigwedge_{j=1}^{n_i} v_{i,j}\right)}\right)}
=\overline{\left(\overline{\bigvee_{i=1}^{m}\left(\overline{\bigvee_{j=1}^{n_i}\overline{v_{i,j}}}\right)}\right)}$$

though the expression is not minimized.